# Combobox con elemento seleccionado basado en un identificador

Tags: java, sql

Tengo el siguiente Formulario:

[image: Aca TEngo un lista de Distritos en el Combobox]

lo que quiero que me ayuden es que al poner un Id del Distrito en la caja de texto, en el comboBox se seleccione el distrito correspondiente al id introducido

[image: de esa manera me deberia seleccionar]

Aca dejo mi codigo

```
public class daoempleado{
conexion.conecta cone=new conexion.conecta();
CallableStatement cst=null;
ResultSet rs=null; 
public DefaultComboBoxModel valorsito(){
  DefaultComboBoxModel valor=null;
   try {           
      cst=cone.xconecta().prepareCall("select * from distrito");
      rs=cst.executeQuery(); 
      valor=new DefaultComboBoxModel();

      while(rs.next())
      {
          valor.addElement(new   beanDistrito(rs.getString(2).trim(),rs.getString(1)));           
      }

      return valor;
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
       return null;
   }
  }
}
```

- Esta es mi clase BeanDistrito

  ```
  public class beanDistrito {
  private String nombre;
  private String id;

  public String getId(){
    return id;
       }

  public String toString(){
    return nombre;
      }

  public beanDistrito() {
    }

  public beanDistrito(String nombre, String id) {
     this.nombre = nombre;
     this.id = id;
     } 
      }
  ```
- Aqui lo llamo en mi formulario despues del initcomponents

  ```
   private void ListarDistritos() {
       cbo1.setModel(d_emp.valorsito());
      }
  ```
- De esta manera

  ```
       public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
          super(parent, modal);
          initComponents();
          ListarDistritos();   
         }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Si es al darle al botón buscar te recomendaría recoger el contenido del textField
y seleccionar el valor del comboBox comparando la id.
 Un ejemplo sería

```
private void buscar() {
    for (int i = 0; i<comboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
        if (persona.getId().equals(textField.getText()))            
          comboBox.setSelectedItem(persona);
    }
}
```

Si no es pulsando el botón podrías usar un listener del textField que cambie el valor del comboBox usando el mismo método.

Saludos y suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas el codigo para capturar el valor? O ya lo tienes pero no te trae el id? Porque veo que cargas el comboBox, pero te harias falta un evento, por ejemplo 'onclick' para cuando selecciones te traigas el indice seleccionado...otra cosa en esta linea cst=cone.xconecta().prepareCall("select * from distrito"); deberias de modificarlo y ordernarlo por el id de manera que cuando selecciones el primer resultado sea el 1

Answer (score 0):

Al pulsar el botón buscar, controlando que introduce un valor correcto (ni espacio vacío ni una letra...) tienes que recuperar el listado de items que contiene el combobox. Una vez que tienes los items, sólo tienes que ir comparando el número introducido en el cuadro de texto y si lo encuentras entre los items marcarlo como seleccionado con el setSelectedItem del defaultcombobox.

Para seleccionar el item, esto creo que lo podrías hacer así (no estoy al 100% seguro de que vaya porque no suelo trabajar con esto pero sería algo así):

```
for(int i=0; i<rs.length; i++)
{
    if((beanDistrito)valor.getElementAt(i).getID()==valor_de_textbox)
        valor.setSelectedItem((beanDistrito)valor.getElementAt(i));
}
```